# Padding of a GtkToolButton

Tags: pygtk, toolbar, padding, gtk

Is it possible to set the padding of a GtkToolButton (in my case, containing a GtkArrow)?

Comment: What padding do you mean? Padding between tool buttons, or between the contents of the tool button and the tool button border?

Comment: Between the content of the ToolButton and the ToolButton border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

- Put a GtkToolItem in the toolbar (`gtk_toolbar_insert`).
- Request a size: in my case, 13x36 (`gtk_widget_set_size_request`).
- Put a GtkButton in the GtkToolItem (`gtk_container_add`).
- Parse some GtkRC code:

  gtk_rc_parse_string(
  "style \"arrowbutton\" {\n" + // Arrows
  "   xthickness = 0\n" +
  "   ythickness = 0\n" +
  "}\n" +
  "widget \"*.arrowbutton\" style \"arrowbutton\"");
- Set the name "arrowbutton" for the GtkButton (`gtk_widget_set_name`).
- Put the GtkArrow (in my case) in the GtkButton (`gtk_button_set_image`).

Answer (score 0):

Tried `GtkContainer.set_border_width` ?

Always follow inheritance hierarchy... for example `ToolButton` is a `ToolItem`, `ToolItem` is a `Bin`, `Bin` is a `Container`, and `Container` has a method `set_border_width`